# Keycloak - How to select the email verification template when sending an email using Keycloak's Admin REST API?

Tags: keycloak

I am using Keycloak's Admin REST API to send a verification email to the user. Specifically, using the endpoint :

```
admin/realms/{realmName}/users/{userId}/execute-actions-email?redirect_uri={redirectURI}&client_id={clientId}
```

The email is sent successfully, but the email template selected by keycloak is "Update Your Account" template instead of "Verify email" template.

Is there a way I can get Keycloak to use the right template?

**UPDATE :**
Tried with the `send-verify-email` endpoint too.. same problem exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am working with Version 3.4.0. If you use the execute-actions endpoint, you cannot choose the template directly. But you can use freemarker to select different content. Here is an example of a `<MY-THEME>/email/html/executeActions.ftl`

```
<#outputformat "plainText">    
<#assign requiredActionsValues><#if requiredActions??><#list requiredActions><#items as reqActionItem>${reqActionItem}}<#sep>, </#sep></#items></#list></#if></#assign>
</#outputformat>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
Actions: '${requiredActionsValues}'<br>
Email: ${user.email}<br>
Username: ${user.username}<br>
</body>
</html>
```

Use the variable `requiredActionsValues` to select your content based on the actions.

Comment: You can take a look at https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/master/services/src/main/java/org/keycloak/email/freemarker/FreeMarkerEmailTemplateProvider.java and https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/master/services/src/main/java/org/keycloak/email/freemarker/beans/ProfileBean.java. Here is the code keycloak uses to fill the email template with variables.

Comment: What does the `<#assign requiredActionsValues><#if requiredActions??><#list requiredActions><#items as reqActionItem>${reqActionItem}}<#sep>, </#sep></#items></#list></#if></#assign>` refer to?

Answer (score 16):

I extended Barnys answer and ended up with this template. 
Don't know why they do not call it a "bug" but a limitation https://issues.redhat.com/browse/KEYCLOAK-5034

for HTML

```
<#outputformat "plainText">
<#assign requiredActionsText><#if requiredActions??><#list requiredActions><#items as reqActionItem>${msg("requiredAction.${reqActionItem}")}<#sep>, </#sep></#items></#list></#if></#assign>
<#assign requiredActionsValues><#if requiredActions??><#list requiredActions><#items as reqActionItem>${reqActionItem}<#sep>, </#sep></#items></#list></#if></#assign>
</#outputformat>


<html>
<body>
<#if requiredActionsValues == "VERIFY_EMAIL">
${kcSanitize(msg("emailVerificationBodyHtml",link, linkExpiration, realmName, linkExpirationFormatter(linkExpiration)))?no_esc}
<#elseif requiredActionsValues == "UPDATE_PASSWORD">
${kcSanitize(msg("passwordResetBodyHtml",link, linkExpiration, realmName, linkExpirationFormatter(linkExpiration)))?no_esc}
<#else>
${kcSanitize(msg("executeActionsBodyHtml",link, linkExpiration, realmName, requiredActionsText, linkExpirationFormatter(linkExpiration)))?no_esc}
</#if>
</body>
</html>
```

for plain text

```
<#ftl output_format="plainText">
<#assign requiredActionsText><#if requiredActions??><#list requiredActions><#items as reqActionItem>${msg("requiredAction.${reqActionItem}")}<#sep>, </#sep></#items></#list><#else></#if></#assign>
<#assign requiredActionsValues><#if requiredActions??><#list requiredActions><#items as reqActionItem>${reqActionItem}<#sep>, </#sep></#items></#list></#if></#assign>


<#if requiredActionsValues == "VERIFY_EMAIL">
${msg("emailVerificationBody",link, linkExpiration, realmName, linkExpirationFormatter(linkExpiration))}
<#elseif requiredActionsValues == "UPDATE_PASSWORD">
${msg("passwordResetBody",link, linkExpiration, realmName, linkExpirationFormatter(linkExpiration))}
<#else>
${msg("executeActionsBody",link, linkExpiration, realmName, requiredActionsText, linkExpirationFormatter(linkExpiration))}
</#if>
```

don't forgot to put the template changes in all instances of the cluster and restart each cluster instance

```
sudo systemctl restart keycloak.service
```

Comment: In the above how to use different mail subject for different required actions.

Comment: did you figure it out @arulraj.net?

Comment: @msek what does the requiredActionsText mean and where did you find it?

Comment: In this case, how can we add the email subject depending on the requiredActionsValues?