# Keycloak templates available variables

Tags: keycloak

I'am googling for a while in order to find a documentation of all available say "variables" I can use in the various Keycloak templates.
by variable I mean all the `${xxx.yyy}` things I can use to inject some dynamic values inside the template.

Through the documentation I can find here and there some of them (like `${user.attributes}` or `${url.resourcesPath}`) but are there others than these ?

Does anyone have a reference link ?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I did not find any easy to use documentation but I found the [Keycloak Javadocs v20](https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/21.0.2/javadocs/org/keycloak/forms/account/freemarker/model/UrlBean.html#getResourcesPath()) which can be helpful when you look for the `*Bean` classes of this documentation. These classes seem to be the ones available in most of the templates. And their public methods will match the available properties you can use in the templates.

For example:
You want to know the properties available for the variable `url` you can check the class `UrlBean` in the documentation and you will find for example a method `getLoginUrl`. This means you can access the property `url.loginUrl`.

That's all I could find for the time being. Hope it will be helpful...

Comment: It certainly helps. I just fear that without a doc, these properties might no longer be available from updates to updates. It's also worth pointing that all properties of a given `*Bean` are not necessarily present all together and if a missing property is used, the template generation fails.

Comment: Indeed! Quite painful to dev and debug without any proper tooling and documentation...

Comment: didn't understand why they do like that... I spent to much time >_< !!

Comment: Link seems to be broken  :/

Comment: Newest link can be found here: https://www.keycloak.org/documentation under API Documentation there is a link to the newest JavaDoc documentation.

Answer (score 18):

You can look for the template providers in Keycloak's code.

All the templates are "ftl" files filled with a map called "attributes". Keycloak has a couple of classes which fill those templates with Beans depending on the page or action as CharlyP mentioned. For example:

- [FreeMarkerEmailTemplateProvider](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/master/services/src/main/java/org/keycloak/email/freemarker/FreeMarkerEmailTemplateProvider.java) class fills the email templates.
- [FreeMarkerLoginFormsProvider](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/master/services/src/main/java/org/keycloak/forms/login/freemarker/FreeMarkerLoginFormsProvider.java) class fills the login templates.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it's what you are looking for, but you can put anything you like in the template as `${xxx}`, as long as you add it in the LoginFormsProvider (or equivalent).

To do so, use the LoginFormsProvider **setAttribute** method, like this (my example uses a UsernamePasswordForm, and Keycloak v15):

```
@Override
protected Response challenge(
    AuthenticationFlowContext context, 
    MultivaluedMap<String, String> formData
) {
    context.form().setAttribute("myCustomTextAttribute", "My custom text");
}
```

Then, in your `.ftl` template, use it like this :

```
<label>${myCustomTextAttribute}</label>
```

Comment: +1! In my case, `createCommonAttributes` in `FreeMarkerLoginFormsProvider` was a good place to override and insert/modify existing attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Keycloak templates available variables:

```html
<#import "template.ftl" as layout>
<@layout.emailLayout>
<img src="https://domain.tld">


<h1>Thanks for signing up!</h1>
<p> Please verify email address ${user.email} <br>activate your account and to proceed registration process.</p>
</@layout.emailLayout>
```

Originaly found on [Keycloak - How to select the email verification template when sending an email using Keycloak's Admin REST API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47345858/keycloak-how-to-select-the-email-verification-template-when-sending-an-email-u)

Good luck !