# Keycloak theme variables - Get client list

Tags: keycloak, freemarker

I have come across similar questions such as [Keycloak theme variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61719874/keycloak-theme-variables) & [Keycloak templates available variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50562384/keycloak-templates-available-variables) which were helpful but I cannot find the variable I need. Is it possible to get the client List of a realm?
This is what I am using to test if the variables are working for me:

```
            <button onclick="console.log('${realm.getName()}')">Test</button>
```

Is it possible to have something like realm.getClient()? I have gone through the models in the code and nothing stands out.